# Activity error in websphere

Tags: java, spring, android-activity, websphere-7

I am trying to run the activity in websphere, which is working in jboss.

```
 <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>  
<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
 <!--  <property name="deploymentResources" value="classpath*:ehrActiviti.bpmn20.xml" /> 
 <property name="deploymentResources" value="classpath*:CorrespondenceGeneratorProcess.bpmn20.xml" />  -->
  <property name="createDiagramOnDeploy" value="true" /> 
  <property name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
  <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
  <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />
 </bean>
```

When I tried to deploy in websphere, I get the following error,

```
    E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /jsp/test/pgActivitiTest1.jsp . Exception created : com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to initialize group definition. Group resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml], factory key [beanFactory]&#59; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name &#39;beanFactory&#39; defined in URL [wsjar:file:/D:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/MohanPW764Node01Cell/eCAMS.ear/ecams.jar!/beanRefContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed&#59; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception&#59; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name &#39;processEngineConfiguration&#39; defined in class path resource [springActivitiContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed&#59; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration &#40;initialization failure&#41;
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.SingleThreadModelServlet.service(SingleThreadModelServlet.java:131)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1384)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
at org.ajaxanywhere.AAFilter.doFilter(AAFilter.java:46)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:852)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:785)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:234)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:859)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to initialize group definition. Group resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml], factory key [beanFactory]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beanFactory' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/D:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/MohanPW764Node01Cell/eCAMS.ear/ecams.jar!/beanRefContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfiguration' defined in class path resource [springActivitiContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration (initialization failure)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:386)
at com.cnsi.activiti.common.template.BusinessTemplateActivitiManager.getProcessDefList(BusinessTemplateActivitiManager.java:121)
at com.ibm._jsp._pgActivitiTest1._jspService(_pgActivitiTest1.java:206)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.SingleThreadModelServlet.service(SingleThreadModelServlet.java:124)
... 28 more
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beanFactory' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/D:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/MohanPW764Node01Cell/eCAMS.ear/ecams.jar!/beanRefContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfiguration' defined in class path resource [springActivitiContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration (initialization failure)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
at org.springframework.context.access.ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.initializeDefinition(ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:381)
... 33 more
      Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfiguration' defined in class path resource [springActivitiContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration (initialization failure)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:110)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
... 46 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfiguration' defined in class path resource [springActivitiContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration (initialization failure)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:44)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:516)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
... 48 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration (initialization failure)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:44)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:516)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
... 65 more
```

I tried adding the jar files in the D:\IBM\Websphere\lib\,
activation 1.1 jar, mybatis-3.1.1.jar, activiti-spring-5.12.1.jar, activiti-engine-5.12.1.jar and also have added these files in the web-inf-lib file.

Can anybody please guide me?.

Thanks

Comment: The "(initialization failure)" means that the SpringProcessEngineConfiguration previously threw an exception from a static initializer.  Search elsewhere in the logs for an exception that includes `SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.<clinit>`, and paste that error/stacktrace into the description.

Comment: That stack trace doesn't have `SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.<clinit>`. Please look through the logs for an earlier stack trace that includes that frame.

Comment: No i dont get such error. That's why i pasted the whole error

Comment: Then I'm not sure what to suggest since the actual cause of the NoClassDefFoundError has been lost.  You could try recompiling SpringProcessingEngineConfiguration to add try/catch+printStackTrace to the static{} (and all static variables), or you could try opening a PMR with IBM to determine why the cause has been lost.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded activity jar through maven and found the following jars missing and added it in websphere\lib folder. Here are the list of jar files,

commons-email-1.2 jar, mail-1.4.1.jar, common-langs-2.4.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, joda-time-2.1.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar, jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar, aopalliance-1.0.jar, commons-dbcp-1.4.jar, commons-pool-1.5.4.jar.

Now it is working. 
Thanks :)